# Clarification on NAT host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, nat

My router has a option to choose a NAT host IP address by specifying the last byte.

What is this host IP address? Isn't NAT on by default in routers? Wouldn't the outside world see the same IP address anyway if any of the devices on my LAN were to send requests? What is the need for a host IP address?

Comment: What router you have?

Comment: @ρss. Apple router.

Answer (score 1):

"Default Host" is Apple's term for what other products may call a "DMZ Host" or "Default Server". You only need to set it if you have a machine on your LAN that runs multiple public services. It's like a catch-all default port mapping/forwarding entry.